# Query where not equal to null or empty

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I am trying to find all the documents where email exists.

I am trying the following find query:

```
{ "email": {$exists:true, $ne:null, $ne:""}}
```

Still I am getting documents where email is `null`.

Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Thanks a lot dude! It worked. Even i suspected the same thing as soon as i posted the question that it's somehow because of the two $ne.

Answer (score 69, accepted):

You want [`$nin`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/nin/) here:

```
.find({ "email": { "$nin": [ null, "" ] } })
```

The problem is [`$ne`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/ne/) is repeated twice and overwrites. You could use [`$or`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/or/) but [`$nin`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/nin/) is shorter:

Given:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("59633c28f5f11516540d118e"),
    "a" : 1.0
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("59633c28f5f11516540d118f"),
    "a" : 1.0,
    "email" : ""
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("59633c28f5f11516540d1190"),
    "a" : 1.0,
    "email" : null
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("59633c28f5f11516540d1191"),
    "a" : 1.0,
    "email" : "fred"
}
```

Just returns:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("59633c28f5f11516540d1191"),
    "a" : 1.0,
    "email" : "fred"
}
```

Also you do not also need [`$exists`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/exists/) when you are actually testing a value. It's already implied that is does "exist".